# How to use jquery event enter key save popup

Tags: magento2

I want save by enter key

1. If enter key -> button save click -> show popup Validate

[image]

Popup validate

[image]

2. If enter key one more time -> click save and show popup Success

[image]

Popup success
[image]

My jquery

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'],function($){
// $(document).keyup(function(event){
//     var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
//     if(keycode == '13'){
//         $("#button-unique-identifier-here").click();
//     }
//     event.stopPropagation();
// });
$("#button-unique-identifier-here").click(function(e){
    var attr = $("input[name$='general[attr]']").val();
    var stocktaking = $("input[name$='general[stocktaking]']").val();
    try{
        if (isNaN(stocktaking) || stocktaking < 1) {
            alert("StockTaking Isn't Number, Please Try Again")
            return false;
        } else {
            if (attr && stocktaking) {
                url = window.validateUrl;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type : 'post',
                    data: {attr: attr,qty: stocktaking},
                    showLoader: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.popupValidate) {
                            var popup = $('<div class="popup"/>').html(data.popupValidate).modal({
                                modalClass: 'changelog',
                                buttons: [{

                                    text: 'Close',
                                    click: function () {
                                        this.closeModal();
                                    }
                                },{
                                    text: 'Save',
                                    class:'save',
                                    click: function () {
                                        this.closeModal();
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                            url: window.saveUrl,
                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            type : 'post',
                                            data: {attr: attr,qty: stocktaking},
                                            showLoader: true,
                                            success: function(data) {
                                                console.log(data);
                                                if (data.success) {
                                                    //popup success
                                                    var popup = $('<div class="popup"/>').html(data.success).modal({
                                                        modalClass: 'changelog',
                                                        buttons: [{
                                                            text: 'Close',
                                                            click: function () {
                                                                this.closeModal();
                                                            }
                                                        }]
                                                    });
                                                    popup.modal('openModal');
                                                } else if (data.error) {
                                                    var popup = $('<div class="popup"/>').html(data.error).modal({
                                                        modalClass: 'changelog',
                                                        buttons: [{
                                                            text: 'Close',
                                                            click: function () {
                                                                this.closeModal();
                                                            }
                                                        }]
                                                    });
                                                    popup.modal('openModal');
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }]
                            });
                            popup.modal('openModal');
                        }else if (data.error) {
                            var popup = $('<div class="popup"/>').html(data.error).modal({
                                modalClass: 'changelog',
                                buttons: [{
                                    text: 'Close',
                                    click: function () {
                                        this.closeModal();
                                    }
                                }]
                            });
                            popup.modal('openModal');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                if(!attr && !stocktaking){
                    alert("Please Enter SKU And STOCKTAKING")
                }
                else if(!attr){
                    alert("Please Enter SKU");
                }
                else if(!stocktaking){
                    alert("Please Enter STOCKTAKING");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch{
        alert("Please Try Again !!!");
    }
})
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use enter key save popup jquery in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264257/how-to-use-enter-key-save-popup-jquery-in-magento-2)

Comment: yeah, I tried that way, but it is not true to my requirements :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
    {
      if($('.yourpopupClass').css('display') == 'none'){

         $("#button-unique-identifier-here").click();

      }else{
         $('.save').click();
      }

    }
});
```

This code will trigger save button on Enter key press.

Comment: I know, but I want to use the enter key to display the authentication pop-up, then enter it again and click the save button to show popup success

Comment: So you want two click on Enter press. One for open popup and one for save ?

Comment: yes, my code when clicking on Enter press, it shows validate popup, one more time, continues show popup validate

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check if this will work.

Comment: Thanks you , I have tried all the class in the popup div but still no, there is no display css :(((